# Date Formulas in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to be able to enter one date in one cell and then have the date read one year out in one cell, 11 months later in another I am using =DATE(YEAR(B4)+1,MONTH(B4),DAY(B4)) and it works great, but I need it to take the info from two cells.

So the date I enter will either be under date joined or date renewed. One date entered into one cell or another cell. output dates come from either of these two cells. One or the other.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and what you would like the formula(s) to return for that sample data? As is, it's really hard to know what exactly you're asking for.

Comment: Our donors are either joining or renewing. B4 cell says Joined. C4 says Renewed. I will enter a date in one or the other of these cells. They are either joining OR Renewing. Cell D4 is when they need to renew a year later using formula =DATE(YEAR(B4)+1,MONTH(B4),DAY(B4)) I can only make the formula read Cell B4 the date joined, but sometimes they are just renewing so I need the formula to also read C4 if there is a date entered there. So it will either be reading the date for B4 OR C4. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by changing the reference to `B4` to be `MAX(B4:C4)`, e.g.:

`=DATE(YEAR(MAX(B4:C4))+1,MONTH(MAX(B4:C4)),DAY(MAX(B4:C4)))`

Technically, due to the way Excel handles dates, you could also just have it be `SUM(B4:C4)` or `B4+C4` as a date added to an empty cell is still the original date (assuming that it's true that only one of the two cells is populated).  Using `MAX` gives you the flexibility that you could keep track of the join date, and also track the latest renewal date.